# How do I view XML files with simple syntax highlighting?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I'm trying to view an XML file in Eclipse, but I'm not enjoying their tree structure view for the XML data. I was hoping there'd be a simple highlighted text view for it but I couldn't find it.

Closest I got was the plain text view which was nearly it.

Is there such a view? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the editor. There should be a source tab that will give you the view you are looking for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Eclipse 4.4, the XML Editor no longer highlights syntax.

Comment: Cerin, are you sure you have XML Editor installed? Some basic Eclipse distributions don't include it.

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for years... and never knew about the "Source" tab when opening an XML. I've always had to open the XML in Notepad++ or VI to get syntax highlighting. Big thanks!