# Eclipse Indigo XML editor doesn't open proper XML files with other extensions

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor, file-extension, file-type

So I have a proper xml file with the ending .xcs
When I try to open it, it give me "Unsupported Contend Type" message.
There it tells me to go to the "Content Type Preference Page" and set the default editor for my file ending.

Now first, this shouldn't happen, because I was specifically opening the file with the XML editor.

Anyway, I go to the Content Type Prefs Page and set the .xcs ending to be opened with XML Editor by default.

Same message when I try to open the file, and when it opens in the XML Editor, the elements don't appear, but instead I get "The document is empty. Right click here to insert content".

One more thing: if I rename my file to .xml it opens without problems.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131448/associate-xml-files-with-the-eclipse-xml-editor which has the answer.

Comment: Is the file actually valid XML?

Comment: yup. the file opens with the correct editor when i rename it to "*.xml"

Answer (score 2):

this solution worked for me

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288239

You will need to change the content type for XML to include the extension .xcs. You can do this by going to Window > Preferences. Expand the tree to General > Content Types. Under the Content Types tree, expand Text and search for XML. Select XML, and then press the "Add..." button. In the Content Type field type "*.xcs". Press OK. Press OK again to save the preference. The .xcs extension should now be associated with the XML content type and the file should open properly in the XML editor.