# How to make XML files always open in the text editor rather than the XML editor?

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

I went to file associations there was no `.xml` format, when I added it, all editors were added automatically and they are static writing me something like:

```
locked by 'XML' content type
```

...can't remove association.

I want that whenever I create an XML file, it would be opened automatically with the text editor.

Please help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[image]

Click default on *.xml and Text editor

Close all files and then try to open an XML file again.

Comment: Was looking for that :). +1, Thanks! @Aubergine: it's custom to accept an answer when it solves your problem.

Comment: What a horrid editor the XML editor is. Wish they would just remove it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Below answer is better. Maven -> User Interface -> Check on 'Open XML page in the POM editor by default'

Answer (score 39):

My problem was that I opened the pom.xml with the maven editor - I wanted it to be opened with the maven editor but to open in the "source" view - achieved it by:

[image]

Typing xml in the search box *did not include this page in the results*.

Answer (score 8):

For people who are looking for a simple text based XML editor, the default XML editor in Eclipse comes with a text based view with syntax highlighting (as it should). It's just not intuitive to know this view exists.

- After you open the file with "XML Editor" the text view can be toggled by clicking on the "Source" tab on the bar just below the file.

By default the view is "Design". "Source" is the simple text based view with syntax highlighting.

For a much better illustration, see:

[How do I view xml in Eclipse with simple syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590119/how-do-i-view-xml-in-eclipse-with-simple-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse IDE,*right click the xml file* and click *openwith* then click **generic text editor**

Comment: This question was asked a decade ago and has a highly upvoted accepted answer. Don't waste your time adding answers to questions like this. Try finding a recently asked question to answer instead.