# GWT UiBinder content assist seems to be missing

Tags: eclipse, gwt, uibinder, content-assist, google-plugin-eclipse

I am not new to GWT & UiBinder development, however it has been a long time since I have used Eclipse for this (I've been using Intellij IDEA the past months).

I am now trying to get an efficient working environment for GWT under Eclipse 4.2, and struggling with the content assist for GWT UiBinder (.ui.xml files).

It looks to me that the only thing that is required is that Google Plugin for Eclipse should be installed, which is:

[image: Screenshot showing the current installation of Google plugin for eclipse]

And probably also that GWT SDK is enabled in the project configuration, which is.

I am also having Maven and Spring on this project, don't know if that could be some content-assist clash.

Anyhow, my problem is that I don't get the content-assist in the ui.xml files. 
I get an error if I'm referencing a class widget that does not exist, but I don't get no auto-completion, nor errors for uiFields being declared in XML and not in JAVA (But i do get errors for UiFields being declared in Java and not in Xml).

Any idea about what could be going wrong?

PS: If I open a < and then use CTRL+SPACE to fire auto-completion, I get the "*Content Assist not available at current location*" error message.

Comment: Did you install eclipse as root/admin? Eclipse functions smoother when installed as the owner-user. Root/admin installed Eclipse frequently results in missing icons or inaccessible content-assist for me. Did you try running eclipse as admin/root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have a XML schema validator / DTD validator set up. Right click your project -> Properties -> Validation it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I do have something similar, with both DTD and XML Schema validators.

Comment: In that case I think you don't have eclipse WTP installed, namely the Eclipse XML Editors and Tools part

Comment: Hum, I do have "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
Version: 3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX
Build id: 20130208151217". Now I'm suspecting something in the project configuration because I haven't created it through the wizard. I'll try to create a GWT project from the wizard to see if there's any difference. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it is caused to the fact that I **misconfigured** my Eclipse Settings regarding the ***default* `XML Editor`**:
When I **open the file directly** with ***Open with -> UI-Binder Template Editor*** it works.

But I could not get it to work so they are auto-associated correctly anymore (opposite to open all XMLs with a specific editor, i.e. [Eclipse how to make xml file always be opened in text editor rather than xml editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915849/eclipse-how-to-make-xml-file-always-be-opened-in-text-editor-rather-than-xml-edi)). It may be due to some manually delete `Toad Eclipse Plugin` and its `DataAdapter Editor` that wanted to open XML files, was the default and I switched the default to the `XML Editor`.
If I should find out how to fix this (playing with the settings in *Preferences -> ... `Content Type`* or *... -> `File assocications`* did not help :-( ).