# Best XML editor for Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I am new to XML. Please tell me the best XML editor plugin for Eclipse. I need to create/edit XML and XSD files.

Comment: IMHO buy Oxygen/XML. It's expensive but worth every penny if you need a good XML/XSLT/XSD editor and debugger. I am not affiliated with Oxygen/XML in any way.

Comment: @@JIM, ok what about the second best :) editor which is free?

Comment: update: I installed the evaluation version of Oxygen/XML. without a doubt it is a complete set with every functionality and flexibility you need.

Comment: The not-constructive-nazis are at it again, isn't this a surprise... -.-

Comment: without a doubt Oxygen/XML is THE best xml editor I have ever used. I purchased the academic version for a cheap price and have been using it for the past ~2 years. It is perfect.

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking for an XML editor before I realized I didn't need one. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590119/how-do-i-view-xml-in-eclipse-with-simple-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a free XML editor that is good enough for your basic XML editing needs, I'd recommend Eclipse own project webtools: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/

Its available from the Eclipse update site at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

Comment: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [market place of Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/).

In this site, you can find any plug-in. Also, it's easy to add it into Eclipse without encountering any problems.

Comment: there is one version compatible with eclipse juno. I used it but it crashes while opening large files(expected though). good for normal jobs.