# Eclipse not syntax highlighting files other than build.xml?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Eclipse is not highlighting the syntax on my web.xml and index.jsp file. In fact the only file it is correctly highlighting is the build.xml which it has identified as an ant build file.

[image]

It seems to just ignore the fact that this is an xml file, not a plain text file. When I highlight over it it gives the message "The word 'xml' is not correctly spelled"?

Also of interest if I copy and paste the contents of build.xml (which has syntax highlighting working fine) into another text file either in the same folder or another then it will not work

I am using Eclipse Juno on Windows 7 64bit

**edit:** as it turns out it was because I was opening the xml files using the text editor. if I open it using Ant editor in eclipse then it has the highlighting

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Comment: You should accept answer from @frogpelt http://stackoverflow.com/a/19691168/248616

Answer (score 9):

As it turns out it was because I was opening the xml files using the text editor. if I open it using Ant editor in eclipse then it has the highlighting

Answer (score 9):

Open your XML file with the XML editor and [select the source tab at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590119/how-do-i-view-xml-in-eclipse-with-simple-syntax-highlighting). This should show you the XML with syntax highlighting enabled.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590119/how-do-i-view-xml-in-eclipse-with-simple-syntax-highlighting)

I am using xml files I created and viewing them in the Ant Editor as Arvin suggested produces errors.

Comment: The current "Kepler" installation does not include the XML Editor by default. However, it is easy to add through Help > Install New Software.