# XML Editor in Eclipse Kepler is not displayed with color

Tags: xml, eclipse, ide, settings

I am really sorry if the question is silly.

I have used Eclipse Galileo,Indigo & Juno and now trying Eclipse Kepler for the development. All the previous versions displayed me the xml syntax coloured wheres in kepler it's not so. Am i missing any settings or configuration? Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, i did this to solve.

Actually there is not a xml editor come along with Eclipse Kepler. So i've just gone into

- **Help**
- **Eclipse MarketPlace**
- Search for **xml editor**
- Find **Rinzo XML Editor**
- Install it

And then to **make it as default one**

- Navigate to Menu **Window**
- Click on **Preferences** --> **General**
- Navigate to **Editors**
- And click on **File Associations**
- If you find *.xml select Rinzo xml editor in the Associated Editors
- otherwise Click on Add on the right side of **File Types**
- type "***.xml**" without quotes and click on add

That's doing a good job for me.

Comment: Note that Kepler release does have an XML Editor. It is just that the package you downloaded didn't include it. See my answer if you wish to install the XML Editor that came with Kepler. Do not know how it compares to Rinzo XML Editor that you found.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik, The built-in XML Editor doesn't support syntax highlighting in my fresh install of Eclipse 4.4... There appears to be an option in its preferences, but it's grayed-out and disabled. That said, Rinzo is pretty bad too. It supports highlighting, but is very slow and will randomly prevent me from entering text in certain locations, like at the top of xml documents.

Comment: @Cerin, are you sure that you actually have the XML Editor installed and that you are using it to open files?

Answer (score 7):

If you do not see XML Editor option under Open With menu, you don't have XML Editor installed. Either get a different Eclipse package (such as Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers) or install XML Editor from Kepler update site.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Just search for XML when the big list of features comes up.

Comment: The URL isn't intended to be viewed in a browser. You need to go through "Help -> Install New Software" menu in Eclipse. Just make sure that you are running a Kepler version of Eclipse before you try to install anything from that URL.

Answer (score 2):

You might have the file open with the Eclipse text editor, not the XML editor. I am not using Kepler, but in previous versions you simply

```
right click the file > Open With > XML Editor
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your answer and sorry i could not find any xml editor. Could be missing?

Comment: Am on Eclipse Neon (4.6.3) and the default XML Editor opens up in the 'design' view. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590200/1154218 pointed me to the solution - just change the view to 'source' once. From the next time, all XML files will open in 'source' view and you would have access to the syntax highlighting too.

Answer (score 1):

[Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) highlights the xml syntax based on the theme you choose.